# Открыть картинку в браузере из веб приложения

Tags: java, tomcat

Здравствуйте. У меня есть картинка в проекте, которая располагается по адресу: 
\src\main\webapp\files\img.jpg
При попытке открыть её в браузере по адресу http://localhost:8080/files/img.jpg вылазит ошибка о том, что невозможно отобразить картинку по такому адресу. Подскажите пожалуйста как быть в данной ситуации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте в web.xml замапить default servlet на каталог с картинками

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

...

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/files/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

[Default Servlet Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html)

Comment: спасибо, все работает. не могли бы Вы объяснить почему доступ к файлам ограничен из вне? зачем это нужно?

Comment: не было обработчика на этот путь, servlet dispatcher не знал куда перенаправить реквест и поэтому отдавал статус 404. указав дефолтный сервлет, томкат будет знать кто должен обрабатывать запросы к "files/*".